# Pandas: Iterate over rows and give values an unique number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, uniqueidentifier

Hello dear people of Stackoverflow. I'd love to get some guidance for a problem I'm getting a small headache from. That's the part where I'm asking for help since my novice knowledge ain't helping me out on that one.

In short: I have a set of a huge amount of data and would like to know how I could give those values an unique number for identifying them. But not several times but only once.

**What do we have and what is wanted**:

- 2 Columns: A and B
- About 200 rows. Some of them are duplicates. I'm only going to post a subset.
- Values can (but not must) appear in both columns A and B. If, then it can happen several times: Maybe just once to several times.
- Every value must be given a number only once. That is important.
- Values starting with 'EB' should be given numbers starting from 300. The next 'EB'-value 301, etc.
- Values starting with 'IN' should be given numbers starting from 400. The next 'IN'-value 401, etc.
- Every value which is not starting with 'EB' or 'IN' should be given numbers starting from 500.
- I would love to have that in the same DataFrame. Every EB-Value with it's number in a column with the name 'C' and 'D', Every 'IN'-Value with it's number in a column with the name 'E' and 'F' and everything else in a column 'G' and 'H'.

**Input**:

```
d = {
'A': ['Rack Ants', 'EB Animals', 'IN Penguin', 'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'T-IPS-ACK', 'AA-BMUL', 'VB-SEM-012', 'VE-PAG'], 
'B': ['EB Animals', 'Applications', 'EB Animals', 'EB Animals', 'EB Humans', 'Applications', 'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'IN Crocodile']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

**What I would like to have (Output)**:

[Click me. Every value has been given an unique number!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGH1F.png)

**My idea (I failed on implementing that)**:

- Iterate through columns A and B, copy distinct values with the start 'EB' into an Array.
- A second array for the distinct values starting with 'IN'. (Just like above no strings with the same name)
- A third array for every value which *is not* starting with 'EB' or 'IN'.
- A function which can be applied on each of those three arrays: Starting with a given value (for example 300), going over every item in the array, writing them in their own column. Next to it will be the number into an own column, upped by +1 for every item in the list. As long as the length of the array.

I hope this post didn't become too long. I'm happy over every help I can get here.

Comment: This is a rather huge request with nearly no previous work from you so far. Stackoverflow is no free coding service. Try to put together some working code and let's discuss specific problems. Read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+unique

Comment: Try so solve it step by step. First unique. Once this works, `EB`, then the next thing. Then the new column depending on the others.

Comment: A request for solving it _completely_ was never asked neither is Stackoverflow seen as a 'coding service'. If you have read correctly you would have seen that I've written that every help is appreciated, even as much as hinting maybe other possible ideas how to solve it. No one is forced to look or writing code for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the DataFrame that you appear to want. For the most part you were spot on about what you needed to do to solve this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def buld_key_df(values:list, number:int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame({
        f'name ({number}s)' : values,
        f'code ({number}s)' : [number + i for i in range(len(values))],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [
        'Rack Ants', 'EB Animals', 'IN Penguin', 
        'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'T-IPS-ACK', 
        'AA-BMUL', 'VB-SEM-012', 'VE-PAG'
    ], 
    'B': [
        'EB Animals', 'Applications', 'EB Animals', 
        'EB Animals', 'EB Humans', 'Applications', 
        'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'IN Crocodile'
    ],
})

unique = pd.concat([df['A'],df['B']]).unique()

df_300 = [x for x in unique if x.startswith('EB ')]
df_400 = [x for x in unique if x.startswith('IN ')]
df_500 = [x for x in unique if x not in df_300 + df_400]

df_300 = buld_key_df(df_300, 300)
df_400 = buld_key_df(df_400, 400)
df_500 = buld_key_df(df_500, 500)

df = pd.concat([df, df_300, df_400, df_500], axis=1).fillna('')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 8)
print(df)
```

[Example code in Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adef%20buld_key_df%28values%3Alist,%20number%3Aint%29%20-%3E%20pd.DataFrame%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f'name%20%28%7Bnumber%7Ds%29'%20%3A%20values,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f'code%20%28%7Bnumber%7Ds%29'%20%3A%20%5Bnumber%20%2B%20i%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len%28values%29%29%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'A'%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Rack%20Ants',%20'EB%20Animals',%20'IN%20Penguin',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IN%20Penguin',%20'IN%20Hippo',%20'T-IPS-ACK',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'AA-BMUL',%20'VB-SEM-012',%20'VE-PAG'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20'B'%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'EB%20Animals',%20'Applications',%20'EB%20Animals',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'EB%20Animals',%20'EB%20Humans',%20'Applications',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IN%20Penguin',%20'IN%20Hippo',%20'IN%20Crocodile'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aunique%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5Bdf%5B'A'%5D,df%5B'B'%5D%5D%29.unique%28%29%0A%0Adf_300%20%3D%20%5Bx%20for%20x%20in%20unique%20if%20x.startswith%28'EB%20'%29%5D%0Adf_400%20%3D%20%5Bx%20for%20x%20in%20unique%20if%20x.startswith%28'IN%20'%29%5D%0Adf_500%20%3D%20%5Bx%20for%20x%20in%20unique%20if%20x%20not%20in%20df_300%20%2B%20df_400%5D%0A%0Adf_300%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_300,%20300%29%0Adf_400%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_400,%20400%29%0Adf_500%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_500,%20500%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5Bdf,%20df_300,%20df_400,%20df_500%5D,%20axis%3D1%29.fillna%28''%29%0A%0Apd.set_option%28'display.max_columns',%208%29%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

edit: It might be more optimal to replace the three list comps for `df_300`, `df_400` and `df_500` with a `for` loop as shown below. This speed increase will only be noticeable if you have a huge amount of unique values you are assigning codes to and if that is the case you'll probably want the codes to be in the tens of thousands not the hundreds:

```
import pandas as pd

def buld_key_df(values:list, number:int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame({
        f'name ({number}s)' : values,
        f'code ({number}s)' : [number + i for i in range(len(values))],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [
        'Rack Ants', 'EB Animals', 'IN Penguin', 
        'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'T-IPS-ACK', 
        'AA-BMUL', 'VB-SEM-012', 'VE-PAG'
    ], 
    'B': [
        'EB Animals', 'Applications', 'EB Animals', 
        'EB Animals', 'EB Humans', 'Applications', 
        'IN Penguin', 'IN Hippo', 'IN Crocodile'
    ],
})

unique = pd.concat([df['A'],df['B']]).unique()

df_30k, df_40k, df_50k = [], [], []

for x in unique:
    if x.startswith('EB '):
        df_30k.append(x)
    elif x.startswith('IN '):
        df_40k.append(x)
    else:
        df_50k.append(x)

df_30k = buld_key_df(df_30k, 30000)
df_40k = buld_key_df(df_40k, 40000)
df_50k = buld_key_df(df_50k, 50000)

df = pd.concat([df, df_30k, df_40k, df_50k], axis=1).fillna('')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 8)
print(df)
```

[Example 2 code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adef%20buld_key_df%28values%3Alist,%20number%3Aint%29%20-%3E%20pd.DataFrame%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f'name%20%28%7Bnumber%7Ds%29'%20%3A%20values,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f'code%20%28%7Bnumber%7Ds%29'%20%3A%20%5Bnumber%20%2B%20i%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len%28values%29%29%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'A'%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Rack%20Ants',%20'EB%20Animals',%20'IN%20Penguin',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IN%20Penguin',%20'IN%20Hippo',%20'T-IPS-ACK',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'AA-BMUL',%20'VB-SEM-012',%20'VE-PAG'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20'B'%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'EB%20Animals',%20'Applications',%20'EB%20Animals',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'EB%20Animals',%20'EB%20Humans',%20'Applications',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IN%20Penguin',%20'IN%20Hippo',%20'IN%20Crocodile'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aunique%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5Bdf%5B'A'%5D,df%5B'B'%5D%5D%29.unique%28%29%0A%0Adf_30k,%20df_40k,%20df_50k%20%3D%20%5B%5D,%20%5B%5D,%20%5B%5D%0A%0Afor%20x%20in%20unique%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x.startswith%28'EB%20'%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df_30k.append%28x%29%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20x.startswith%28'IN%20'%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df_40k.append%28x%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df_50k.append%28x%29%0A%0Adf_30k%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_30k,%2030000%29%0Adf_40k%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_40k,%2040000%29%0Adf_50k%20%3D%20buld_key_df%28df_50k,%2050000%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5Bdf,%20df_30k,%20df_40k,%20df_50k%5D,%20axis%3D1%29.fillna%28''%29%0A%0Apd.set_option%28'display.max_columns',%208%29%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Sorry for answering that late. I really wanted to thank you. Your solution is super elegant and helped me out a lot. Really, thanks again!